# How to properly bundle Express server and PUG engine with Webpack?

Tags: webpack, pug-loader

If a pug template served by Express lives in `./src/client/views/index.pug`.
And Webpack is bundling the Javascript / CSS and has a config to output a pug file..

```
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/client/views/index.pug',
    }),
```

And Express is set to serve this route from it's view directory..

```
app.set('views', path.resolve(__dirname, '../client/views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

res.render('index');
```

How is it possible to use Webpack dev server to serve this index with the bundled assets?